# regex selects zero prefix to avoid negative lookahead

Tags: regex

I have (hopefully) the full example here: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/Cfh

I need to add absolute paths to css url with relative path. (I'm merging several css files in different locations, so relative paths to the original location doesn't work)

For instance

`background-image: url("star.gif");` ->
`background-image: url("/images/star.gif");`

But not `background-image: url(https://example.com/images/star.gif);`

I'm using `preg_replace('/url\((["\']?)(?!(\/|http(s)?:|data:|#))(.*?)\1\)/mi', 'url("/images/$4")', $input_lines);`

An url can be sourrounded by 0 or 1 single or double quotes, but they must be balanced. `(["']?) ... \1`

url should not start with / http(s): data: or # `(?!(\/|http(s)?:|data:|#))`

But `url("https://www.example.com/style.css")` gets turned into `url("/images/"https://www.example.com/style.css"");`

because regex selects zero quotes, so `"https:` doesn't match `http(s)?:`

Without quotes the rexex doesn't match, which is good. `url(https://example.com/images/star.gif);`

Is there a way to stop trying to match if a negative lookahead has given a match?

Comment: One obvious and probably-good-enough fix is to turn `.` into `[^"']`. There is a more elegant solution using backtrack control (though I am not very good at it). (I see you are using PHP's `preg_replace`, so you should additionally tag with [tag:pcre] (or at least [tag:php]), per rules in the [tag:regex] tag.

Comment: Add the optional quote into the negative lookahead `url\((?!["']?(?:http|data|#))(["']?)(.*)\1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the "probably-good-enough" solution in the comment (because most URLs don't contain quotes), here's two more correct solutions, with a caveat that they use features that are not available in every regexp dialect.

You can say "once I've found whether or not there is a quote, I will not change my mind" using `{*PRUNE}` (disallowing any backtracking to its left):

```
url\((["']?){*PRUNE}(?!(\/|http(s)?:|data:|#))(.*?)\1\)
```

or using [atomic groups](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.onlyonce.php) (locking in that one decision):

```
url\(((?>["']?))(?!(\/|http(s)?:|data:|#))(.*?)\1\)
```

Comment: Your [^"'] suggestion worked fine. the {*PRUNE} didn't work on the tester as you suspected, but the final solution is what I'll use in the css-combiner-minifier for smarty.